# Activity implementation of interface function defined in BottomSheetDialogFragment is not being called

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I want to communicate between activity and fragment using the standard approach but got stuck in something. I don't know why?
Here is my code for **BottomSheetDialogFragment:**

```
@override
   public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.camera_icon) {
            photoShareCommunicator.photoShare(10);
        }
    }
```

And on activity side I have implemented **photoShare()** in main activity as:

```
@Override
    public void photoShare(int resultCode) {
        Log.d("shiv", "Something click!!!");
    }
```

And *photoShareCommunicator* is defined as:

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try{
            photoShareCommunicator = (PhotoShareCommunicator) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            Log.d("Shiv", "Class Cast Exception!!! : " + e);
        }
    }
```

Now I don't know why **photoShare()** function is not executed in main activity.
Need Help??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please anyone. It's very neccessary

Comment: Please show more of your code. Is onClick() getting called when you click `R.id.camera_icon` (Put a log statement in your onClick to check)? Where is your Interface definition? Where are you setting your callback?

Comment: @SoundConception Yes onclick is called and Interface is defined inside fragment. Callback is set inside "PhotoShareCommunicator" class.

Comment: Please show more of your code, otherwise we are just guessing. There is nothing wrong in the small code snippets you've shown so far, so the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @SoundConception I have corrected the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android studio it is not working first. So I uninstalled the app and then installed on device. Now everything is fine.